# How to add anchor tag to ngx-datatable-column

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I need to load data from server and load the ngx-datatable. On click on a particular column (link`<a href="randomurl"/>` or [routerLink]="randomcomponent"), it should redirect to different page or it should show a modal window.

I am new to Angular 2 +

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! As far as I can see, you don't have a question and already found the answer (; you mentioned href and routerLink - have you any code you're struggling with or any specific question? Please be a bit more specific to make it easier for us the understand your exact problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It worked, I used ng-template to accomplish it.

Reference: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/row-detail.component.ts